# Xcode 7 permanent code coverage overlay

Tags: swift, xcode7, code-coverage

I've just tried out Xcode 7's support for generating and displaying code coverage data from Swift code. It works, but I have to move my mouse over the little numbers on the side to see the overlay in the editor, and I have to do it individually for each function.

Is there a way to have Xcode show the coverage overlays throughout the code without having to hover the mouse pointer somewhere and to have it show the uncovered code with a red overlay? That's how coverage tools usually do it and I think it's a better approach than those little number, because you can see at a glance what parts of the code you haven't tested yet.

If Xcode can't do it, are there third-party tools that can show the coverage in that way and can read profdata-files?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Codecov](https://codecov.io) here an example project: https://github.com/codecov/example-swift

Thank you!